# Will a website made using HTML and any server side language (PHP, .net, ruby) work on each device which has browser?

Tags: php, javascript, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

If we want to make a web application/website and want maximum compatibility

Will a website made using HTML and any server side language (PHP, .net, ruby) work on each device which has browser? No CSS, No JS, No Images.

Will it cover at-least 90% of devices which can connect to internet and have web browsers?

Comment: Your question is not stupid as the downvotes would imply.  There are no stupid questions :)

Comment: HTML will "work" in any HTML-interpreting client.  Is there a particular reason you would think otherwise?

Comment: As long as your HTML is standards compliant.

Comment: If you don't use any CSS or images your site is going to look very bland though. Think of it this way(very basic and rough analogy): HTML = timber you use to build your house; Server side language = Method of delivery for your timber to building site; CSS = the pant and wall coverings to make your house aesthetically nice.

Comment: @wanovak Technically, even if it's not. A browser won't refuse to display a site if it contains invalid HTML - it just might render it incorrectly.

Comment: @newfurniturey Oh, yeah, I thought that was a requirement. You're right.

Comment: @scrappedcola - That i already know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what a server side language does is decide what HTML to send to the client (at its most basic). A client will never see any of the actual server side code. This means that compatibility is determined by the HTML that is output by the server side language, not what language was used to create the HTML.

So the answer to your actual questions would be, yes any server side language and yes it would cover at least 90% of devices that are able to render HTML (depending on the validity of the HTML).

Answer (score 4):

HTML will render on any device that has an HTML-supporting browser (iPhone, Android, etc.). So, if your website is written with HTML - you should be fine.

The server-side languages, PHP, .Net, Ruby, etc - they are all executed server-side and have nothing to do with the client's device other than generating dynamic content and sending it as HTML. So, I guess the technical answer could be "yes - any device with a browser is covered by all server-side lanagues", pending they return renderable HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the market. In many parts of the world, many mobile browsers still only show WAP/WML. Otherwise, as you noted a "server-side" language is just that and thus has no bearing on the issue. If it's just plain HTML, that will work on many mobile devices. The exact percentage will vary depending on market.

The newer standards you use, the fewer devices will be able to display it properly. Also keep in mind by not using things like CSS and images, while more people may be able to see it, you'll likely get more people leaving the site because of how it looks and works.

Comment: +1 As this is only commentary on here that mentions older WAP browsers, which really suck to develop HTML for.  Of course, if you are really only concerned with modern devices (iOS, Android, Symbian S60 5.0+,, etc.). Then they all have full web-kit based browsers so they won't be a problem.

Comment: @MikeBrant - yes because of the application i'm talking about will need dynamic things so I think it will not work with WAP enabled devices, that's ok. even if i cover 80% devices of world, it's enough

Comment: @JitendraVyas You can still produce HTML source code dynamically for consumption by WAP browsers.  As others have pointed out the dynamic nature of the content is not the problem, it's just the WAP browsers tend to work best with WAP-specific DOCTYPES and HTML constructs.  I personally have not spent any time worrying about WAP-specific development in over 3 years and I am in the mobile industry, so you are probably right in not worrying about it unless you have a specific target market where such devices might still be common.

Comment: @MikeBrant - Do know if WAP user can fill and submit web forms.

Comment: @JitendraVyas http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wml/wml_inputs.htm

Comment: @JitendraVyas Yes use can use forms in WAP. Though many of the WAP browsers have really poor UI's for trying to do so.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs server-side only. The browser NEVER receives PHP code (unless there is a major configuration error in your web server).
So it will work in all browsers as long as what you generate with PHP is understandable by a browser.